# how to count data in a certain column in python(pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

hope you're doing well .
i tried counting green color row after another green colored row in the table below
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[green], [red], [red]], columns=['A'])

the code i tried to count greengreen:

```
 for index,row in data.iterrows():
   if finalData['Color'].loc[i]=='green' & finalData['Color'].loc[i+1]=='green':
    greengreen+=1
    i+=1
```

but it didn't work,hope you can help. note: i'm new to data science

Comment: can you please remove the image and provide the example data as text instead? (`print(df.head())`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# is the color green?
m = df['color'].eq('green')
# count the matches that precede another match
greengreen = (m&m.shift()).sum()
```

As a one-liner (python ≥ 3.8):

```
greengreen = ((m:=df['color'].eq('green'))&m.shift()).sum()
```

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'green']})
```

output: `3`

Comment: thank you it worked, can it be used for red green or green red?

Comment: Yes but you need to use two masks then (maybe open a new question with an example of what you want exactly, please follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for your example).

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {'col1': ['A','B','C','D'],\
        'col2': ['green','green', 'red','green']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | green |
| 1 | B | green |
| 2 | C | red |
| 3 | D | green |

```
df.col2.values
greengreen = 0
greenred = 0
redgreen = 0

for i in range(len(df.col2.values)):
  if i < (len(df.col2.values)-1): 
    if df.col2.values[i] == 'green' and df.col2.values[i+1] == 'green':
      greengreen += 1
    elif df.col2.values[i] == 'green' and df.col2.values[i+1] == 'red':
      greenred += 1
    elif df.col2.values[i] == 'red' and df.col2.values[i+1] == 'green':
      redgreen += 1
    else:
      print('?')

print(greengreen, greenred, redgreen)
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```py
count = (df['Color'].eq('green') & df['Color'].shift().eq('green')).sum()
```